# Listbox with Wrappanel won't show elements

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel

I'm quite perplexed as to why when I drop in a WrapPanel for my Silverlight 4 ListBox ItemsPanel, nothing shows up.  If I only comment out the ItemsPanel, I get a normal vertical list of my little pictures with text.  I added the background color to the WrapPanel just to convince myself the WrapPanel was actually there.  I assume I'm missing something boneheaded, what is it?

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             MinHeight="24"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border> <StackPanel> <Image> <TextBlock> </StackPanel> </Border> (pseudo template)
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Background="Orange" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you see wrap panel at all or you still see white background?

Comment: I dont see any issue, but is this your final project? and does it reference all necessary dlls for toolkit, for example, toolkit.dll depends on basetoolkit.dll. your usercontrol will allow you to add wrappanel from toolkit.dll but if you do not reference basetoolkit.dll it might give error, dont know if this is the case but it can be one of the reason, what do you see in designer view? do you find any other error in Visual Studio's Output window (debugger) when you run the project?

Comment: I do see the orange background.  I used NuGet to add a reference to 'Silverlight Toolkit - Layout'.  I don't see any errors in the output window related to this.

Comment: I added a separate wrappanel to my window, with two elements in it.  It is displaying properly.

Comment: The items in my listbox are not only not visible, they are not being constructed - because two of the URI's I'm setting for Image.Source are invalid.  I catch exceptions if I use the default ItemsPanel.

Comment: DockPanel shows the same behavior of WrapPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've clueless as to why, but switching to an ObservableCollection for my ItemsSource did the trick.  No clue why things would behave differently for the default ItemsPanel than a diff't panel, but it did.

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your item template has any substance to it - it's full of empty elements. Put something in there and you should see results. e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry for the pseudo xaml.  I'd hoped the lack of closing tags would make that clear.  Also, I said that if I comment out the wrappanel, things show correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your scenario using Blend's sample data and I can see the items inside the wrap panel:

```
    <UserControl
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
        x:Class="ASD_Answer012.MainPage"
        Width="640" Height="480">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Property2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Property3}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Width="64"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsWrapPanelTemplate">
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Background="DarkOrange"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsWrapPanelTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

This is what I get:
[image: WrapPanel Items]

Maybe if you provide more detailed XAML it will be possible to reproduce the exact issue and solve it.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I tried moving my stuff to the Resources, and copy/pasted your ItemsPanel stuff, to no avail.